# Java 8 map each field value of a List to another similar List

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 List of objects:

```
List<User>
List<UserResource>
```

For `User` class:

```
public class User {

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String address; 

    **SETTERS & GETTERS**
}
```

For `UserResource` class:

```
public class UserResource {

    private String name;

    private String address; 

    **SETTERS & GETTERS**
}
```

My `List<User>` has data and i want to map **value** in `name` and `address` to `UserResource`'s `name` and `address`, using java 8 stream and lambda, but i not sure how to do it.

Search online for quite sometime but not able to find similar question. Something like:

```
List<User> users = **data inserted**
List<UserResource> resources = users.forEach(u ->{
    u.setName(users.getName());
    u.setAddress(users.getAddress());
});
```

I tried something like following, but im not using constructor, not really sure how to fix it.

```
List<UserResource> userResources = users.stream().map(u -> new UserResource(u.getName(), u.getAddress())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Try something *not* involving `forEach`…

Comment: yes yes! i knew there are something we can do with `stream` and `map` but not really sure how to do it.

Comment: See [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) and the [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/package-summary.html). The latter has an example in the “Mutable reduction” section which needs only little adaption to your use case…

Comment: @hades you must try it by yourself first. if you meet some problem, you can ask as a question.

Comment: well your edit is correct... what is not working? u want to do it via setters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your edit is logically correct, I assume you want to do it via setters, in this case define a lambda body and perform the operations there...

```
.map(u -> { 
     UserResource ur = new UserResource();
     ur.setName(u.getName());
     ur.setAddress(u.getAddress());
     return ur;
 }).collect(...)
```

Comment: yes! this is what i mean, didn't know can do it this way, thanks