# How to process element of list to another list in single line in java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8

There is a list of `View2` object, I want to add the `Id` of `View2` object in `List<Integer> Ids`. I want to process the above operation in a single line of code.

```
class View1{
  List<Integer> Ids;
}
class View2{
  Integer Id;
}

List<View2> views2 = getViews()
```

Want to something like following.

```
view1.setIds(view2.forEach(s -> s.getId()));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 map each field value of a List to another similar List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952425/java-8-map-each-field-value-of-a-list-to-another-similar-list)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
 view1.setIds(view2.stream().map(View2::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```